# Is there any jquery plugin available to show recent search history

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

Currently in my application, I have search box which show list of matching items. 
For that I am using simple `jQuery` contains method right now.
[image]

Now what I want to do is show recent search texts also with some dropdown icon and search image.
[image]

For that I want to know if there is any `jQuery` plugin available, or else how can I achieve this.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/14-jquery-live-search-plugins/

Comment: http://tkyk.github.io/jquery-history-plugin/

Comment: Pooja, What you have to do is implement a live search  / auto complete script with the text box. You have to store the search keywords in the database and show in the auto completion out put  when user type some keyword. You can use either Jquery Auto complete plugin or Twitter TypeAhead  plugin . Twitter typeAhead gives more look and feel for the auto completion .

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Comment: Twitter typeahead : https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

Comment: What I want is on click or some button(like search icon with arrow in image above), It should display the history. Auto complete can help me creating a list of texts searched. But, It will show only on typing and will show matching words only. Instead i want all recent texts to be displayed below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to do so wihtout using any jquery plugin. Posting solution just in case someone is looking for same.

I used simple bootstrap components and classes. An input field, Places search icon on its left side with attribute data-toggle dropown which will display list items and placed one button on right of input field which whil save text from input field.

Here is how my soluiton looks like-
[image]

```
           <div class="pull-left dropdown">
                <span rel="localize[tabs.workflows]">&nbsp;</span>
                    <a id="show-search-history" class="" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> <i class="icon-zoom-in"></i> </a>
                    <ul id="search-list" class="dropdown-menu search-list-menu" >
                        <li>qq</li>
                        <li>op</li>
                        <li>new</li>
                        <li>wf</li>
                        <li>2</li>
                        <li>oj</li>
                    </ul>

                <input type="text" name="search" value="" id="search-wf" placeholder="Search Workflow" autofocus />
                <button id="save-search-text" class="btn" style="">Save</button>
            </div>
```

And css changes:-

```
.search-list-menu {
min-width: 230px;
right: 53px;
top: 88%;
}
.search-list-menu li:hover {
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
background-color: #0088cc;
}
.icon-zoom-in {
z-index: 999;

}

a#show-search-history {
left: 35px;
position: relative;
top: 5px;
text-decoration: none;
}
#save-search-text {
border-radius: 0 14px 14px 0;
height: 30px;
margin-left: -20px;
}
```